Failing USB internet connection
I have been trying to connect my Pi Zero to the internet over USB on Ubuntu, and Windows. I am failing. I have gadget mode set up. And, I can ssh in. I have shared my internet connection. I cannot ping my router from the Pi. network unreachable.
ifconfig -a
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 11002  bytes 741026 (723.6 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 11002  bytes 741026 (723.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

usb0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.55.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.248  broadcast 10.55.0.7
        inet6 fe80::eca2:69ff:fee5:a21a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether ee:a2:69:e5:a2:1a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1717  bytes 157506 (153.8 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 672  bytes 116452 (113.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

`
